# phpmyadmin not loading on RPi 4 64 bit

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, raspberry-pi

I tried to install phpmyadmin using:

```
sudo apt -t buster-backports install phpmyadmin
```

Following [this guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=283586) because I'm on the 64 bit version of Raspian.

When trying to access `http://<ip>/phpmyadmin` I see the php code.
How do I get this to work?

[php code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfJEP.png)

```
pi@rpi4-metal:/var/www/html $ sudo apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.46 (Debian)
Server built:   2021-01-20T07:40:46
```

```
pi@rpi4-metal:/var/www/html $ php -v
PHP 7.3.27-1~deb10u1 (cli) (built: Feb 13 2021 16:31:40) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.27, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.27-1~deb10u1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

```
pi@rpi4-metal:/var/www/html $ sudo a2enmod php7.3
ERROR: Module php7.3 does not exist!
```

This is on a RPi 4:

```
pi@rpi4-metal:/var/www/html $ uname -r
5.10.11-v8+
```

Comment: Seems you have the CLI version of PHP installed and not the web version.

Answer (score 0):

To correct, I did

```
pi@rpi4-metal:~ $ sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php -y
pi@rpi4-metal:~ $ sudo service apache2 restart
```

and now it works.

Version is still the same:

```
pi@rpi4-metal:~ $ php -v
PHP 7.3.27-1~deb10u1 (cli) (built: Feb 13 2021 16:31:40) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.27, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.27-1~deb10u1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```